# ArrayList<ContentValues> in alphabetical order

Tags: java, android

I want to add alphabetical order to arraylist from db(whatever values).
my code like this

```
ArrayList<ContentValues> array_main = new ArrayList<ContentValues>();
ContentValues values1 = new ContentValues();
values1.put(MyHelper.OVEN_ID, _id);
                        values1.put(MyHelper.USERNAME, user);
                        values1.put(MyHelper.DESCRIPTION, des);
                        values1.put(MyHelper.IMAGE, image);
                        values1.put(MyHelper.DATE, date);
                        values1.put(MyHelper.NAME, title);
                        values1.put(MyHelper.FOOD, food);
                        values1.put(MyHelper.RATING, rates);
                        values1.put(MyHelper.INGREDIENTS, ingre);
                        values1.put(MyHelper.DIRECTIONS, direct);
```

i can change only MyHelper.Name to alphabetical order in arraylist. and thanks for responsibility.

Comment: show us what have you tried so far

Comment: Try to sort the collection

Comment: please show `ContentValues` object

Comment: Did you try Googling? There are tons of links explaining this: http://bit.ly/1hfDjmF

Comment: have you even tried goolgle? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4031572/sorted-array-list-in-java

Comment: thanks for your response. i have edit my contentvalues code here.

Answer (score 0):

You could let your database do the sorting when you get the information from the database

```
....
Arraylist<objecttype> newList =new ArrayList<objecttype>();
String selTable = "select * from object order by object_name desc";
s.execute(selTable);
ResultSet rs = s.getResultSet();
while((rs!=null) && (rs.next()))
 {
    newList.Add(rs); //something like that
 }
```

Use Asc or Desc in your select statement, depending on how you want to sort.

Comment: in contentvalues i can change myhelper.name to alphabetical order after select from db.