# Algorithm in saving elements in array maintaining order

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures

I have on one random number generator which generates number between `1 to k`. Also i have array of `int` type (i.e `int[]`) ,whose size is `N` , where `k` is smaller than N .

Now problem is i need to save unique generated numbers into array (rejecting the generated duplicate number) and has to maintain order of generated numbers , without using any extra space and in `O(N)` complexity. i.e i same array i need to maintain order of generated number also. So that i can retrieve them in generated order. No bitmap or extra array etc is suppose to use.

Its not a homework. Its one of the interview question. I am not supposed to  use any extra space. He asked me to use the fact that `k` is smaller than `N` and you need to inculcate the behavior of hashmap in same array. I proposed many algorithms using extra spaces but he rejected also using sorting , but i was not able to maintain generated order.

Comment: If I were you, I'd 1) save my elements to a sorted list, and 2) call toArray() when I'm done.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4031572/sorted-array-list-in-java.  PS: This sounds like homework?

Comment: Can you show us what code you have so far? What approach(s) are you considering?

Comment: "*without using any extra space*" seems like impossible task. Even for swapping you need `int temp` that takes 4 bytes.

Comment: "*same array need to maintain order of generated numbers also*" Another impossible task since array can have only one *order*.

Comment: @PM77-1: "without using any extra space" usually refers to not creating an array which length depends on the input, in other words, using `O(1)` additional space is ok. In his statement "same array I need to maintain order of generated numbers also", OP is a bit vague, I agree, but he obviously only one order here if you read the whole question carefully, the order for which the random numbers are generated.

Answer (score 5):

OK, I'll buy this isn't homework. Here's the solution. Suppose k=3, N=5

Start:

```
ar[0] = 0
ar[1] = 0
ar[2] = 0
ar[3] = 0
ar[4] = 0
```

Generate a random number. Suppose it's 2. We need to store two bits of information now:

- "2" is the first random number.
- "2" is taken.

So we do this:

```
ar[0] = 2
ar[1] = 0
ar[2] = 10  // 10 is any number that's larger than N.
ar[3] = 0
ar[4] = 0
```

next number: 4

```
ar[0] = 2
ar[1] = 4
ar[2] = 10  // taken
ar[3] = 0
ar[4] = 10  // taken
```

next number: 2

```
ar[2] >= 10 thus taken, try another number
```

next number: 1

```
ar[0] = 2
ar[1] = 14  // added 10 to signify it's taken
ar[2] = 11  // added 1 as it's the current number
ar[3] = 0
ar[4] = 10  // taken
```

Done.

Now, iterate through array, and subtract 10 from everything that's larger than 10. you'll end up with

```
ar[0] = 2
ar[1] = 4
ar[2] = 1
ar[3] = 0
ar[4] = 0
```

One caveat - this assumes random numbers are in `[1..N]` range. if they are `[0..N-1]`, you'd have to tweak a bit.

Comment: Does such algorithm have a name?

Comment: @iluxa: Probably you meant to add `N*2` instead of `k*2`. Adding `k*2` will result in ambiguity whether the number has already been taken or it's just a number being generated as such (for example for `k=2`, and `array[1] = 5`, you don't know whether it's actually really number 5 with no `1` has been generated, or that it's a 1 with `1` has been generated. Using `N*2` (actually `N` suffices), you can check whether the number is greater than `N`, then subtract `N` from it if it is. This algorithm will be correct since the max value is `N`, so anything > `N` is a sign that something was there.

Comment: generated numbers only go up to k, so i ~think~ k+1 would suffice. But hey, N*2 + 1000000 for good merit

Comment: Generated numbers can go to `N`. `k` is the number of random numbers to be generated. Anyway, I guess negating the number will be better, it's more intuitive =D

Comment: @PM 77-1: "the famous iluxa algorithm for solving a random homework" i suppose :)

Comment: Oh no, you can't negate zero in uninitialized parts of the array, haha. Sorry, we need your `+N` method then

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41576/discussion-between-justhalf-and-iluxa)