# Java collection interface that guarantees no duplicates as well as preservation of insertion order

Tags: java, collections

Is there a java collection interface that guarantees no duplicates as well as the preservation of insertion order at the same time?

This is exactly what LinkedHashSet is doing? However, I am wondering if there is also an interface guaranteeing the same thing in order to avoid direct dependency on some specific class?

SortedSet is referring only to the natural order (and is not implemented by LinkedHashSet).

Essentially, I am looking for an interface that would indicate that the iteration order of elements is significant (and at the same time it contains no duplicates, i.e., List obviously would not apply).

Thanks!

**UPDATE** this question is not asking for an implementation or a data structure (as in the question to which this was marked as a duplicate). As several people pointed out as clarification, I am looking for an **interface** that demands both properties (no duplicates and significant order) in its *contract*. The application for this would be that I can return objects of this type to clients without promising any specific implementation.

**UPDATE 2** Moreover, [the related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4031572/sorted-array-list-in-java) specifically asks for preserving duplicates in contrast to this question. So I am pretty certain it is not a duplicate.

Comment: how do you expect an interface (without any implementation) to guarantee this? for instance, you can say interface MyInt{ void doNotPrintThisString(String s); } class A implements MyInt{ public void doNotPrintThisString(String s){ System.out.println("ha-ha!!"); System.out.println(s); } }
It's the implementation that can guarantee something.

Comment: @Stultuske I think OP means to say he is looking for an Interface that states the mentioned behavior in the contract.

Comment: might be, but no matter what the method names in an interface are, it can guarantee only that the implementing class provides an implementation, and that's it.

Comment: AFAIK, All the "Linked" collections preserve insertion ordering in their iterators. So the answer to your question is Yes, LinkedHashSet does that. The other answer, as Stultuske pointed out, is No, there is no INTERFACE that guarantees such a thing (you can make your own, though!).

Comment: No. There is no such *interface* guaranteeing such a contract. `LinkedHashSet` is an *implementation* that does.

Comment: You are looking for a combination of the `Set` and the `Queue` interface. Even then `Queue` does not demand FIFO behaviour, it also allows LIFO or priority queues. Actually even a `Iterable` would be enough to iterate over the collection, but you still depend on the actual implementation to guarantee FIFO behaviour (like `LinkedHashSet` provides).

Comment: `Set s = new LinkedHashSet()` gives you the behavior you want without a dependency on the implementation. If you want that behavior as part of the public contract you either specify `SortedSet` or the `LinkedHashSet` neither is incorrect if you want to expose the contract.

Comment: Guava's [`ImmutableSet`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableSet.html) does that. If you follow Guava's recommendations, you use `ImmutableSet` everywhere you need it.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson How can this be a duplicate of the other answer ? The other is to put a new element in its naturally ordered place explicitely preserving duplicates, this one is to maintain insertion order with no duplicate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No interface in the JDK collections provides that.

You could try to build it by combining `Set` and `List`. Any collection implementing `Set` should not allow duplicate elements, and any collection implementing `List` should maintain order.

But then, no class in the JDK collection implements both `Set` and `List`. Because unfortunately `LinkedHashSet` does not implement `List`.

Of course, you could build one implementation easily by wrapping a `LinkedHashSet` (by composition patter, not by derivation) and adding a `get(int i)` method, or by wrapping an `ArrayList` (again by composition) and throwing an `IllegalArgumentException` when trying to add a new element.

The most tricky part IMHO would be the `addAll` method as both interfaces define it with different semantics (emphasize mine) :

- `Set`: Adds all of the elements in the specified collection to this set **if they're not already present**
- `List` : Appends all of the elements in the specified collection to the end of this list, **in the order that they are returned by the specified collection's iterator**

As you cannot meet both requirements is source collection contains duplicates, my advice would be that `addAll` throws an `IllegalArgumentException` in that case, or more simply that it always throw an `UnsupportedOperationException` as `addAll` is an optional operation for both interfaces

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is what I was suspecting. It is surprising to me though. BTW: regarding your notes, I just need an iterable collection with significant order and without duplicates. So no index access is actually necessary. I have to see if I just want to add an interface for that. Most importantly, I did not want to miss out on a potentially already existing JDK interface. Cheers.

Comment: 1+. I deeply _hate_ the omission of such a marker interface as creating generic methods around "Collections" becomes a mess, a huge one.