# What is the most efficient way (speed-wise) of maintaining a sorted ArrayList in Java?

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist, collections

Which of the following two methods would be the faster one of keeping an `ArrayList` sorted ?

- Inserting the element in its place
- Calling `push`, then call `Collections.sort(myList)`

Comment: Depending on what you are using it for, [`SortedSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/SortedSet.html) ?

Comment: I want to have a list of Users(which is a separate class)  whose ids must be in ascending order.Here I used Integer as an example in order not to complicate the question

Comment: I think the answer from smonff is the one that makes the most sense: do not build your interfaces around fixed data structures. Instead, select that data structure that gives you what you need; without building additional layers around it.

Comment: I am kind of new to Java and it was the best approach I could think of.Thank you for your answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is different kinds of collections. You could [choose one that keeps your data sorted](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/intro/index.html).

Comment: If the op needs random access, I don't think the JDK provides a sorted alternative...

Answer (score 2):

It would probably be more efficient to insert in the right position, for example by using `Collections.binarySearch(list, elementToInsert)`:

```
int index = Collections.binarySearch(list, element);
if (index < 0) index = - (index + 1);
list.add(index, element);
```

---

If you don't need random access and your entries are unique (which seems to be the case based on your comment), you could also use a TreeSet:

```
NaivigableSet<User> users = new TreeSet<> (Comparator.comparing(User::getId));
```

The set will always be sorted based on the user ids which must be unique.

Comment: If I will be using your method, my `User` class will have to implement `Comparable<User>` and `Comparator<User>`, right?

Comment: @gusteru In the first example yes, although you can provide your own comparator if required: `Collections.binarySearch(list, element, Comparator.comparing(User::getId))`. In my second example I have already provided a comparator based on ids so no need for User to be Comparable in that case.

Answer (score 0):

If your requirement asks for a continuous sorting after every insert, i think you should try alternate approach than the current one as this in itself is not time efficient. For a elaborate explanation for possible solution you must look at [Sorted array list in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4031572/sorted-array-list-in-java)